# C# WPF external usb button

Tags: c#, wpf, button, usb

I have an external USB button and I want to create an event every time I click on the button. So if I click on the external button there should be an output like: "External button clicked".
I have barely any experience in USB communication in C#. My idea was to detect the external usb and its ID.
I am thankful for any tips and ideas.

Comment: To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

first of all if you want to detect your USB device in your application, maybe you need to know the **vendor ID** and **product ID** of your device that will be the necessary drivers to communicate with your application. You can do this very easily in the device manager tool for Windows OS.

Here is a small tutorial:
http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-find-unknown-device-drivers-by-their-vendor-device-id/

Once this is done, depending on the library you're using and the communication protocol used, there are functions that allow you to detect your device using your vendor id & product id.

Here is an example project for .NET that I've used before which uses HID *(Human interface device)* protocol, for testing:
http://www.usbhidnetclass.com/?page_id=226

In this project, there are functions like this:

```
 easyUSBHidNetClass1.DeviceUSB_Config_VID_PID(0x1234, 0x0001); //VID and PID
```

That allows you to detect your device in your own application.

Hope it helps!